# made angular scope available in Django TemplateResponse()

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django

I am using `Python/Django` as back-end for framework and `angular` as front-end. At some point I am using `TemplateResponse()` in view function to get template response, this template includes `HTML/CSS/JS/Angular` code . `TemplateResponse()` can complie every other code but not angular bec angular scope is not available.

Here is sample code :

**Django code**

```
 t = TemplateResponse(request,
                             'dynamic-content.html',
                            {'raw_html':raw_html,
                            'raw_css':raw_css,
                            'raw_js':raw_js,
                            'js_script':js_script,
                            'css_script':css_script,})
t.render()
```

Now I'll send `t.content` to angular which will include template response.
In angular I'll use directive to make angular scope available in the above template response .

```
<div dynamic="t.content"></div>
```

Directive :

```
app.directive('dynamic', function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.dynamic, function(html) {
        ele.html(html);
        $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

But the time b/w providing angular scope to template response takes time.
Another issue is `js` gets compiled before angular scope available.

So either I have to make `angular` scope available in Template or stop `js` to get compile before angular.
What approach i should take regarding this . Please help.

Comment: Try to ask question in a simple language . Instead of adding too much of literature, be specific to your problem . And add the problem your are facing in some sample code.

Comment: @csharpcoder edited my question . Hope now you will get idea about my problem

Comment: I don't understand this question at all. TemplateResponse doesn't "compile" any kind of code, let alone Javascript. And `t` is a Python variable, which isn't sent to the template - it's the context variable itself, is not *in* the context - so using it in any HTML is impossible.

Comment: @DanielRoseman  using t.content in template only means that I first stote t.content in a variable and then pass it to the angualr as a response

Comment: Perhaps you should post the code where you do that.